# How does the salary calculator combine inputs?

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

In my testing it *appears* the calculator has a lookup table for each input (Role, Location, Education, Years of experience, Technologies).

Then it appear the lookup provides a percentage increase or decrease which is applied to some base salary.

Further it appears that each input category is applied completely independently from each other.

In other words if I select "hacklang" (which is a big increase) it always produces the same percentage increase despite changes to other inputs (Full Stack, Gfx/Game, SysAdmin).

I'm wondering if my inferences here are correct. Because the blog post discussed some impressive models however I'm suspicious the calculator is ignoring most of the good stuff.

Comment: Shhh!  You weren't supposed to test it...just assume all the models and stuff are there and working correctly